# how to have JPanel both horizontally and vertically in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

[image]

i am trying to make screen as in the picture using swing.

My code snipet

```
Label l1,l2,l3;
JPanel p1=new JPanel();
JPanel p2=new JPanel();
JPanel p3=new JPanel();
l1=new Label("Employee:);
l2=new Label("Earning");
l3=new Label("Deductions");
p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
p1.add(l1);
p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
p2.add(l2);

p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK)));
p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK)));

JPanel container = new JPanel();
container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
container.add(p1);
container.add(p2);
container.add(p3);
add(container,BorderLayout.NORTH);
setVisible(true);
setSize(600,600);
```

with Y_AXIS it doesn't allow me to have 2 panel side by side.

how to have panels both horizontally and vertically

Comment: Based on the screenshot, GridBagLayout would be very applicable for what you want to achieve

Comment: thanks..works perfect with GridBagLayout